# How to split the row by a comma and unpivot the table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

I have this table and I want to split the column by the comma and unpivot it

The table I have

```
+------------+-------------------+---------------------------+
|birthday_id | child_birthday_id | place                     | 
+------------+------------------ +---------------------------+
|  1         |        9          |  Minsk, Mogilev, Polotsk  | 
+-------+----------+-------------+---------------------------+
```

and I want to have 3 rows with different places

```
+------------+-------------------+----------------------+
|birthday_id | child_birthday_id | place                | 
+------------+------------------ +----------------------+
|  1         |        9          |  Mogilev             |
|  1         |        9          |  Minsk               | 
|  1         |        9          |  Polotsk             | 
+-------+----------+-------------+----------------------+
```

I know how use in MSSQLS server using CROSS APPLY but in Postgres IDK

```
SELECT 
    birthday_id , 
    child_birthday_id,
    place
FROM 
    sh.test
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(place, ',');
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried already. Explain why/where it failed. Be specific (error message, unexpected result, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `string_to_array()` and `unnest()`

```
SELECT t.birthday_id , 
       t.child_birthday_id,
       p.place
FROM sh.test t
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(string_to_array(place, ',')) as p(place);
```

If you are using Postgres 14 you can also use `string_to_table(t.place, ',')`

Comment: Do you need the `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`? Can you not simply do `SELECT birthday_id, child_id, unnest(string_to_array(place, ', ')) as place FROM demo GROUP BY 1, 2;`?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock: no you don't really need it. But I prefer to be explicit when doing a cross join

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server's `CROSS APPLY` translates to `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` in Postgres. To split a string into a table, you can use `regexp_split_to_table()`.

```
SELECT t.birthday_id,
       t.child_birthday_id,
       p.place
       FROM sh.test AS t
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_split_to_table(t.place, '\s*,\s*') AS p
                                                                            (place);
```