# how to convert connect BY in postgreSQL. What will be the conversion of this oracle stored procedure code in postgreSQL stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, oracle

```
select DECODE('''||v_month||''',''0'',''0'',regexp_substr('''||v_month||''',''[^,]+'', 1, level)) 
from dual 
connect BY regexp_substr('''||v_month||''', ''[^,]+'', 1, level) is not null
```

I have tried conveting it using chatgpt and https://www.sqlines.com/online but its not able convert it as expected

Comment: Please post the code you currently have and describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: Your code is very well converted in both ChatGPT and the above site if you remove extra quotes (which are hightlighted by SO's syntax highlighter)

Comment: Also check these: [Splitting a comma-separated field in Postgresql and doing a UNION ALL on all the resulting tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9232572/2778710), [How to split the row by a comma and unpivot the table in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70452373/2778710)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not valid SQL as `''0''` and `''[^,]+''` are not a valid string literals. You either want `'0'` and `'[^,]+'` or `'''0'''` and `'''[^,]+'''`.

Once you fix it then you get:

```sql
SELECT DECODE(
         '''||v_month||''',
         '''0''',
         '''0''',
         REGEXP_SUBSTR('''||v_month||''','[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
       ) 
FROM   DUAL 
CONNECT BY
       REGEXP_SUBSTR('''||v_month||''', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
```

And `'''||v_month||'''` is a string literal; it is not prepending and appending a single quote to a variable so your query can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT '''||v_month||'''
FROM   DUAL
```

Which, in PostgreSQL, would be:

```sql
SELECT '''||v_month||'''
```

---

If you do want to recurse through your a comma-delimited string then, in Oracle, you can use a recursive query and simple string functions:

```sql
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT v_month FROM DUAL
),
bounds (value, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT value, 1, INSTR(value, ',', 1)
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value, epos + 1, INSTR(value, ',', epos + 1)
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SELECT CASE epos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, spos)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, spos, epos - spos)
       END AS month
FROM   bounds
```

PostgreSQL has the `string_to_array` function which does it automatically and then you can `unnest` to convert to rows:

```sql
SELECT UNNEST(string_to_array(v_month, ','))
```

[Oracle fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TMBRg6z4)
[PostgreSQL fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MWM3ephh)